# Direct Digital Synthesizer using Cordic Algorithm using C

Tags: c, user-interface, cordic

I want to ask if it is even possible to create a software that produces a wave form from using CORDIC Algorithm to make a Direct Digital Synthesizer?

Also, since I'm new, I'm using C since that's what our professor wants us to use, and also, do you guys have any code on a very simple GUIs without any function, only just the window, file, edit, help taskbars?

Comment: Please only one question per post. If you want to ask another question, please create a new post via [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: if that so, please answer the only first question. Thanks! I'm new here so, my bad.